# Am I Missing something on storyboards?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I'm tring to make a view controller shows a table view controller but i want to show the navigation item inside the navigation bar from each table view controller. All the table view controller will have navigation on right items. I was testing only in the first one on top of the image

Am I doing right?

[image]

Comment: "All the table view controller will have navigation on right items" What does that mean?

Comment: why have you taken tabBarController?

Comment: Didn't get your problem. Can you explain it?

Comment: @matt i putted navigation bar and bar button items and didn't work

Comment: @ShabbirAhmad i want a tabbar after pushing the + button

Comment: @RahulKumar i want to put a bar button item on navigation bar but isn't working

Comment: "i putted navigation bar" That's your mistake. Use the navigation bar provided by the storyboard; do not drag _another_ navigation bar into the interface! If a view controller lacks a place to put bar button items, drag a Navigation Item — not a navigation bar — onto that view controller.

Comment: @ThiagoSuchorski, In storyboard, Goto your view controller -> click Naviagtion item -> drag and drop BarButtonItem

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the new update. Change the segue from Adaptive "Push" to Deprecated "Push"

Comment: I'll try this when I reach my home

Answer (score 0):

1: Select an `UIViewController` (The first one with the TabBarIcon, i.e your `UITableViewController`)

2: Click **Editor** in the top menu **-> Embed In -> Navigation Controller**

[image]

Comment: do i need to put another navigation controller?

Comment: Yes. A navigationcontroller for each tabBar->nav->vc. Otherwise your UI seems broken and probably will be too.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you

1. On your view controller's navigation bar add -> **Navigation item** -> on that add **Barbutton Item**
   [image]